# MySQL enforce uniqueness across two columns

Tags: mysql, unique

I'm trying to achieve something in MySQL that I have not heard is possible before (maybe it is, researching didn't help me much).

What I'm trying to do is enforce uniqueness in MySQL across two columns. What I mean by this is not setting UNIQUE(column1,column2) but the following two conditions:

1. If a value exists in column1, it cannot be repeated in column1 (same as setting UNIQUE(column1)).
2. If a value exists in either column, it cannot exist in the other column.

Hence, for the data set {column1,column2}, if {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} are data already present, then neither of the two columns can have any of the above data items for new data,i.e. new data item {x,y} where x=NOT{column1} AND y=NOT{column2} AND x!=y

Is this possible? Please help me out here. Thank you.

Comment: You ll need a trigger here

Comment: You would need to set up insert and update triggers to do this.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I was hoping there was a built in solution for this. I guess the fact that column1 and column2 are ENUM with the same choices doesn't help either. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: what would be the best way to achieve this? trigger or stored procedure? In terms of implementation simplicity and speed of execution?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an overkill, but you can store `column1` and `column2` in a separate table.

Let's say your table is

```
create table items (
    id int primary key,
    column1 int,
    column2 int
);
```

with data:

```
id | column1 | column2
---|---------|--------
 1 |       1 |       2
 1 |       3 |       4
 1 |       5 |       6
```

You can change your schema to

```
create table items (
    id int primary key
);

create table item_columns (
    item_id int,
    position int,
    val int,
    primary key (item_id, position),
    unique key (val),
    foreign key (item_id) references items(id)
);
```

with data:

```
item_id | position | val
--------|----------|----
      1 |        1 |   1
      1 |        2 |   2
      2 |        1 |   3
      2 |        2 |   4
      3 |        1 |   5
      3 |        2 |   6
```

You can simulate the old schema with

```
select i.id, c1.val as column1, c2.val as column2
from items i
left join item_columns c1
    on  c1.item_id = i.id
    and c1.position = 1
left join item_columns c2
    on  c2.item_id = i.id
    and c2.position = 2
```

You can use it in a view if you like.

Demo: http://rextester.com/PPBT42478

To guaranty the integrity for the `position` column, you can make it a foreign key to a `positions` table, which will only contain the values `1` and `2`. You could also use `ENUM('1', '2')`, but ENUM always allow an empty string as a value.