# Detect duplicates within two MySQL columns (unique values scattered across columns)

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a MySQL table that contains identifiers spread across two columns:

```
left right
1    2
3    6
4    5
```

Using SQL how to find out whether  the table contains any duplicate identifier?

For instance, the example above is OK but the examples below are not OK:

```
left right
1    2       <--+
3    6          | Not OK
4    1       <--+

left right
1    2
3    3       <-- Not OK
4    5

left right
1    2
3    6       <--+ Not OK
4    6       <--+
```

I am legally not allowed to modify anything in this database, so my question is not about [enforcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560914/mysql-unique-across-two-columns) this in the schema or via triggers or stored procedures I can not modify the database's schema, but rather how to check using just SELECT-type operation(s).

If it was a single column I would write `SELECT left FROM MyTable GROUP BY left HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;` but for two columns I am not sure how to proceed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get all values, left and right, in one column:

```
select value
from 
(
  select left as value from mytable 
  union all
  select right as value from mytable 
) all_values
group by value
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

if any any values of left exist in right then it is duplicate so you use sub-query and `aggregate` function

```
select case when count(*)>0 then 'deplicate' else 'not' end as result  from your_table
    where left  in (select distinct right from your_table t2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce69b8/2